# Ошибка при установке NODEJS

Tags: веб-сервер

Что делать?

```
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/www/node/work/node-v0.8.18/out'ln -fs out/Release/node node===>  Installing for node-0.8.18===>   node-0.8.18 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 - found===>   Generating temporary packing list===>  Checking if www/node already installed===>   node-0.8.18 is already installed      You may wish to ``make deinstall'' and install this port again      by ``make reinstall'' to upgrade it properly.      If you really wish to overwrite the old port of www/node      without deleting it first, set the variable "FORCE_PKG_REGISTER"      in your environment or the "make install" command line.*** Error code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ясно же написано, что сначала нужно удалить прежнюю версию через "make deinstall", а потом поставить заново, посредством "make reinstall" (это, как я понимаю, чтобы старые конфиги подхватило)!Но если хотите с чистого листа, то "make clean" и "make install"!